# no values persisted in database when running spring boot JPA test

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was looking at solutions of mapping column default value in `spring-data-jpa` which lead me to documentation of `@ColumnDefault` annotation; and I wanted to try it out. So I updated an entity where we needed default values (today this is handled via a schema.sql where we define additional column behaviours) like so:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@DynamicInsert
@NoArgsConstructor
@Relation(collectionRelation = "customers")
public class Customer extends Organisation implements Identifiable<Long>, Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8101819808147191270L;

  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 3)
  @ColumnDefault("'INR'")
  private String currency;

  @Column(scale = 2)
  @ColumnDefault("0.10")
  private Double tds;

  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 3)
  @ColumnDefault("'INV'")
  private String invoicePrefix;
```

Now since I'm using the `@ColumnDefault` I expect that default values are configured for the column, which they are when I look at the database. However, when I run a test to insert values; the defaults fields are `null`. I configured Postgresql for the test (as production will be in Postgresql); While the DDL for table in Postgresql shows default values are added to 
table definition

```
CREATE TABLE data_api_it.customer
(
    currency character varying(3) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INR'::character varying,
    invoice_prefix character varying(3) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INV'::character varying,
    tds double precision DEFAULT 0.10,
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT customer_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk3afgab8nfy6ykn6b70uuh9v59 FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES data_api.organisation (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Here's the test that fails

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest(showSql = false)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { DataApiJpaConfiguration.class })
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application-it.properties","classpath:application-test.properties"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class CustomerRepositoryIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

  @Test
  public void testPrePersistAddsMandatoryFields() {

    Customer bhau = new Customer();
    bhau.setName("Bhau & Sons Pvt. Ltd.");
    bhau.setDomain(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8));
    bhau = customerRepository.saveAndFlush(bhau);
    Customer badaBhau = customerRepository.findById(bhau.getId()).get();
    assertThat(badaBhau.getTds().doubleValue()).isEqualTo(0.10);
    assertThat(badaBhau.getInvoicePrefix()).isEqualTo("INV");
    assertThat(badaBhau.getCurrency()).isEqualTo("INR");
  }

}
```

The failure is a `NullPointerException` at `assertThat(badaBhau.getTds().doubleValue()).isEqualTo(0.10);` when I run on debug I notice that `badaBhau` indeed doesn't have the default values set when queried from the database. I then paused after the line when it persists `bhau`; browsed test database configured and noticed that the `bhau` entity isn't even saved to the database in the first place.

I also ran the app with Postgesql Dev DB trying to hit the API url for saving customer with the JSON data

```
{
    "name":"Minty and Sons Pvt. Ltd.",
    "pan": "AASONAL123",
    "domain": "xy123456"
}
```

this call succeeds in creating the record of course with default values `INR`, `INV`, `0.10` for `currency`, `invoice_prefix` and `tds` respectively.

So while I understand and like how `@ColumnDefault` solves the default value issue for me; I'm utterly confused as to what why the test fails (or what am I doing wrong)

Comment: How are you injecting `customerRepository` bean?

Comment: updated test case code, I'm using `spring-boot-starter-test` so most of it is auto configured

Comment: *updated test case code*. Why? I can assure you, you already have the explanation in the 2 answers below.

Comment: Can you add the SQL generated for the insert statement as I would be interested to see what Hibernate generates here? In terms of the docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/sql-insert.html) inserting null to a non-null column should **not** result in the column value being set to the default. Is Hibernate using the `default` keyword in the insert statement?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to see here but I thought you wanna see how I am using the `customerRepository` hence shared it. Yes the problem has been solved by following the recommendations in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Hibernate's first-level cache, `bhau`  and `badaBhau` will be the same instance, viz. there will be no database lookup triggered by the following: instead the customer with the specified ID will be retrieved from the first level cache. You can verify this by enabling SQL logging.

`Customer badaBhau = customerRepository.findById(bhau.getId()); //no db lookup`

To have the value can force a database lookup by clearing the persistence context or by refreshing the persistent instance.

```
public class MyTestClass {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test
      public void testDefaultFieldsArePopulated() {

        Customer bhau = new Customer();
        bhau.setName("Bhau & Sons Pvt. Ltd.");
        bhau.setDomain(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8));

        bhau = customerRepository.saveAndFlush(bhau);
        em.clear(); //db lookup will now happen

        Customer badaBhau = customerRepository.findById(bhau.getId());
        assertThat(badaBhau.getTds().doubleValue()).isEqualTo(0.10);
        assertThat(badaBhau.getInvoicePrefix()).isEqualTo("INV");
        assertThat(badaBhau.getCurrency()).isEqualTo("INR");
      }
}
```

https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/understanding-hibernate-first-level-cache-with-example/

Crizzis also raises a valid point in his answer and as the test passes it looks like Postgres is then replacing nulls with the column's default value. As you may not be able to depend on this across different database engines then you could also look at using Hibernates `@DynamicInsert` annotation on your entity which would create an insert statement with only non-null fields set.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicInsert.html

> For inserting, should this entity use dynamic sql generation where
>   only non-null columns get referenced in the prepared sql statement?

Comment: Plus what crizzis mentions in his answer.

Comment: yes clearing the persistence context passes the test.

Comment: thanks for the added explanation `@DynamicInsert` was configured, the problem was not explicitly specifying nullable and the entity manager clear as you pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Part of my answer was going to be what @AlanHay already mentioned.

Even when you follow his advice though, I'd still expect your test to fail. The purpose of  `@ColumnDefault` is to use the specified default value with the column definition **when executing DLL, no more, no less**. The default value means: 'whenever the value for the column is not specified in an `INSERT` statement, use the following value instead'.

The thing is, you *are* specifying a value for the column, since your column is not excluded from the `INSERT` statement using `insertable = false`. Even if you didn't set a value to the property, Hibernate will send an explicit `NULL`. Your approach *may* work for `currency` and `indexPrefix`, since you marked them as `nullable = false` (this is DB-specific, and you'd have to consult the docs to see how Postgres handles such a situation). I highly doubt it will work for the `tds` column, since `NULL` is a valid value in that case.

Comment: though just the `em.clear()` call passes the test and I can see an additional select query in the logs now, I agree keeping the column explicitly not nullable is also a good thing, that ways the intent is documented better in code.

Comment: See also Hibernate's `@DynamicInsert` annotation which would create an insert statement with only non-null fields set. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicInsert.html

Comment: yup that I had configured at the time of sharing the question.